# Alternative to ListView inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have been trying to hack a ListView into a ScrollView. As many threads have pointed out, this is a very bad practice (see [How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing?lq=1)). I am currently measuring the height of my ListView and fixing its size using the solution proposed here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495908/924217), which works perfectly for equal height rows, but is measured incorrectly for variable height (reports min height for all rows). For quick and dirty fix, does anyone know how to measure the height properly for variable height rows?

More appropriately, can anyone point me to a good workaround using LinearLayouts. I am trying to use a ListView because I have items which I need to dynamically add and remove to the list. I cannot think of any convenient ways of doing this without adapters and the other niceties appropriated by a ListView. Can someone help me find an example of this being handled properly? Also, are there any open source projects which cover this? I have seen many people asking similar questions with little non-hacky resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend that you should use listfragment so that you can dynamically add/remove items.

Comment: I agree that fragments may help facilitate a modular design, but that still doesn't solve the issue of a ListView being embedded in a ScrollView. This creates a problem primarily due the handling of touch events.

Answer (score 0):

here parentScroll = your main scrollview and childScroll = your listview

```
parentScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.v("PARENT", "PARENT TOUCH");
                    findViewById(R.id.child_scroll).getParent()
                            .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            childScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.v("CHILD", "CHILD TOUCH");
                    // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
                    // child view
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```